# what does hooking of Dom objects mean

Tags: javascript, dom

in my project i am parsing JavaScript code especially dynamic functions like `document.createElement` with regexes. but i was suggested to wrap `document.createElement` to make hook. i am not understanding how to do

they also provided an example:

```
var f = document.createElement; 
document.createElement = function(tagName){ 
    console.log(tagName); 
    f.apply(document, arguments); 
}
```

This code is tracking `document.createElement`

i am unable to understand how this can be used in my code can anyone help me

Answer (score 2):

That code will store a reference to the original `document.createElement` and then reassign `document.createElement` to point to a new function.

Inside of this new function, it will log the first argument and then call the original `document.createElement()` passing `document` as its `this` value and passing the rest of the `arguments` as they were.

Here is how I would code it...

```
(function() {
    var documentCreateElement = document.createElement;

    document.createElement = function(tagName) {
        console.log(tagName);
        return documentCreateElement.apply(document, arguments);
    }

})();
```

If `console.log()` may not be available, you may want to change that line to...

```
window.console && console.log && console.log(tagName);
```

Comment: in short, `document.createElement` was "customized"

Comment: what is the output of this function and how can i use this for tracking all the document.createElement functions in a web page

Comment: @user1275375 Place it so its defined before you call `document.createElement()` and each call will log the first argument.

Comment: sorry to ask but i am unable to understand the concept of hooking moreover i have to track the document.createElement() methods in a page to see if any dynamic script is created i am trying to do this with user-scripts. And also i am clueless how to add the function in my code. I understood that it should be included at the start of the program but how can i do it. sorry to bother you again but i am trying on this from past 2 hours i also goggled it but i am not understanding anything.